# Devolver un valor booleano desde una funcion y pasarla a una condicional

Tags: javascript, funciones, boolean

tengo una función que valida si los hermanos de un selector tienen una clase diferente y retorna un valor true para utilizarlo posteriormente en un else if.

```
 var product = $('.slide-product.isHidden');
function productSiblings() {
            $(product).each(function(){
               if($(this).siblings(':not(.isHidden)').length > 0 ) {
                 return true;            
               }
            });
        };
```

Luego quiero utilizar productSiblings() como una expresión condicional para poder entrar a este else if

```
 else if(productSiblings()) {
            $carousel.show();
            preselectedView (preselectedL,preselectedR);
        } else {... }
```

La pregunta sería si  el return true me sirve para validar o bien cómo puedo hacer para que el else if funcione.

Answer (score 3):

Sí. Claro que el `return true` te sirve para realizar la validación en el `if`.

El `if` te debería funcionar sin problemas. Si devuelve `true` cumple la condición y si no la función va a devolver `undefined` que no va a cumplir la condición del `if`.

De todas formas por claridad del código deberías hacer que la función devolviera siempre un valor (`true` o `false`). Algo así:

```
var product = $('.slide-product.isHidden');
function productSiblings() {
     $(product).each(function(){
        if($(this).siblings(':not(.isHidden)').length > 0 ) {
          return true;            
        }
     });
     return false;
};
```

Comment: Hola gracias por responder, si agrego el return false por fuera del each, no estaría tomando ese valor la función productSiblings cuando la utilizo en el else if donde luego la utilizo ?

Comment: Sí claro, en caso de no encontrar ningún elemento que cumpla la condición devolverá false. No como ahora que no devuelve nada. Al final la diferencia es que al if le va a llegar false en lugar de undefined. El resultado va a ser el mismo pero creo que el código queda bastante más claro.

Comment: Pero si digamos, entra en el if, toma el valor true, luego sale del each, cuando sale volverá a cambiar el valor y lo que necesito es que me valide cuando es true y cuando no. mmm no me queda muy claro,porque primero es return true, sale del each y se vuelve return  false, pierde el valor que necesito para usarlo en el else if? qué piensas ?

Comment: Cuando haces `return true` dentro del bucle eso provoca que finalice la ejecución de la función y devuelva el valor `true`. Del bucle únicamente va a salir si ningún elemento cumple la condición.

Comment: La función tal cual está escrita siempre devolverá false: ejecutará el foreach, que no provoca un return, y luego el return false

Answer (score -1):

La función `.each` de jQuery no devuelve nada, simplemente ejecuta la función que se le pasa N veces (para cada elemento) pero ignora los resultados. Por tanto, si quieres hacer comprobaciones para cada elemento y devolver true si alguno de ellos cumple una condición, tienes que guardar el resultado fuera de la función parámetro:

```js
function productSiblings(p) {
  let result=false; //guardamos en una variable externa el resultado
  $(p).each(function(){
    if($(this).siblings(':not(.isHidden)').length > 0 ) {
      result= true; // si encontramos un caso en el que se cumple, modificamos la variable
    }
  });
  return result; //devolvemos el resultado
};

let third=$( 'li.third-item');
let one=$('.one');

console.log(productSiblings(third));
console.log(productSiblings(one));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="isHidden">list item 1</li>
  <li class="isHidden">list item 2</li>
  <li class="third-item one">list item 3</li>
  <li class="isHidden">list item 4</li>
  <li class="isHidden">list item 5</li>
</ul>

<ul>
  <li class="isHidden">list item 1</li>
  <li>list item 2</li>
  <li class="third-item">list item 3</li>
  <li>list item 4</li>
  <li>list item 5</li>
</ul>
```